# vim 8.0 file explorer only allows specific locations

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, netrw

I'm running Vim 8.0 on a Windows 7 system and I'm having this issue whenever I open gvim (the one that runs in a window as opposed to running in `cmd`) the default path in `:pwd` is `c:\users\"user"`. If I use the `:Explore` command it brings up the file explorer showing all the files in there but I can only go up in file paths up to `c:\users` and that's it, I can't go any upper than that.

More than that if I use the `:cd` command to go to a different drive (`d:`), it does change the directory successfully and it does show it if i use `:pwd`. But if I use `:Explore`, it doesn't show anything, instead it just does a split screen of the same file containing the same text i have in the initial file.

Furthermore, if I create an `asdasd.txt` file in `d:\` and open it with Vim and then use `:Explore`, again it does nothing, just goes back to the same line of text I was on in command mode, almost as if the program is looking for access to that directory or cancelling the command because of something like that.

Also, I used Vim 7.4 before this and the commands mentioned worked as expected. Any ideas what the problem might be? Does it need any special configuration?

Comment: Crosspost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323605/vim-8-0-file-explorer-only-allows-specific-locations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its generally best to try the latest netrw when one has a problem, because that problem may have already been addressed.  You can get the latest netrw (v162i) from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW .  I think this problem, in particular, has been addressed already, although I don't have a windows box handy to try it out at the moment.

Comment: Can confirm. This is a known issue (Reported by me :P). The new version of netrw has a fix for it.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot. yeah i found out that there's a bug with netrw but for whatever reason it comes with the latest version of vim but yeah, that worked. :)